# Eclipse 3.3.2/MyEclipse doesn't recognize xml as ant files

Tags: eclipse, ant

Using eclipse 3.3.2 with MyEclipse installed. For some reason if a file isn't called build.xml then it isnt' recognised as an ant file. The file association for *.xml includes ant and says "locked by 'Ant Buildfile' content type.

The run-as menu is broken. Even if the editor association works run-as doesn't.

The ant buildfiles in question are correctly formatted. They work fine if you call them build.xml or if you use them anywhere else. Eclipse just won't recognise and thus wont allow you to run them.

Answer (score 3):

The environment inspects the file contents to determine if it is an Ant file (if it isn't called "build.xml"). Add the following to the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="myproject" default="t1">
    <target name="t1"></target>
</project>
```

You should now see the "Ant Editor" in the "Open With >" menu when you right-click on the file.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and found that the Ant Tools weren't included in the Eclipse binary I downloaded.  You can try installing the Eclipse Java Development Tools. These can be found under Java Development > Eclipse Java Development Tools in Help > Software Updates > Available Software.

Comment: In Eclipse Indigo (3.7) this is now at Help > Install New Software... then Programming Languages > Eclipse XML Editors and Tools.  

Note that when you open a file the XML editor defaults to 'design' mode, which looked rubbish and worse than unhighlighted XML to me. To switch between design and source mode there are a couple of tabs at the bottom of the editing area.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the "File Associations" page (Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations) you should see a list of all file types which Eclipse recognises. Scroll down to the "*.xml" entry, highlight "Ant Editor" in the "Associated Editors" pane and hit the "Default" button on the right-hand side. Eclipse should now open any XML files with the ant editor.